# Get and pass row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My customer needs a popup which shows details or edit ...etc, but he also needs those buttons (details or edit) to be in the top of the table (outside table) not for each row, so I need to get the id of a selected row then pass it to button and open the popup

**Briefly, I need to select row then click a button and finally show the popup**

my code is like that.

the table:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="tblId">
<tr>
    <th>
        <label>supplier id</label>
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink(" supplier name ", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm }, new { @class = "icon-arrow-up" })
    </th>

</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SuppNO)
        </td>
        <td>

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SuppName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail btn btn-primary icon-list" id="btndetails" type="text"> Details </a>
```

Popup:

```js
 
        var TeamDetailPostBackURL = "/M_Supplier/Details";
        $(function () {
            $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                //var returnValue;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "id": id },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal(options);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#closbtn").click(function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        });
```

and this my tries to get row id and highlight selected ones, and it works fine but i don't know how to pass the id

```js
    //get id
    $(document).on('click', '#tblId tr', function getid() {
        var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();

        //alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[1]));
        alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]));
        //return tableData;
    });
    //end

    //hover clicked row
    $("#tblId tr").click(function () {
        var clicked = $(this).data('clicked');
        $(this).data('clicked', !clicked);
        if (clicked) {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#fff');
        }
        else {
            $(this).children().css('backgroundColor', '#ffdc87');
        }
    });

    $("#tblId tr").hover(function () {
        $(this).children().css('hover', '#ffdc87');
    }, function () {
        if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
            $(this).children().css('hover', '#fff');
        }
    });
    //end
```

Comment: Fairly routine to toggle a *selected* class on rows and use that as target when click on button

Comment: I tried it but it looks I needed an example to clarify it, but the answer below did the job, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using jquery only and some custom modal:

Explaniation:

1. I declared a global variable to set the row the buttons can trigger.
2. I use delegation event to each table row in order to set the variable value.
3. it also use a simple modal with 2 different divs the first one show the data, the second one the form where you can edit the records.
4. After a target is selected the buttons trigger the sepecific modal div to work with, anytime the modal is closed the target variable length is set in order to select a new row.
5. each button have a loop to fill the fields with the same order of the row cells.

```js
let target;
$('#tableFood tbody>tr').on('click', (e) => {
  target = e.target.closest('tr');
  $(target).css("background-color","#3b8bf5");
  //console.log(target)
})
$('#btnGetRowInfo').on('click', (e) => {
  if ($(target).length > 0) {
    $('#showInfo').empty();
    $('#idNumber').text($(target).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    $(target).children('td').each((i, e) => {
      $('#showInfo').append(`<p>${e.textContent}<p><br>`)
    })
    $('#modalExample,#showInfo').css("display", "block");
  } else {
    alert('Please select a Row !!!')
  }
});
$('#btnCancel,.close').on('click', (e) => {
  $('#modalExample,#showInfo,#showEdit').css("display", "none");
  $(target).css("background-color","#fff");
  target = '';
});
$('#btnGetRowEdit').on('click', (e) => {
  if ($(target).length > 0) {
    $('#showEdit').children('input').val('');
    $('#idNumber').text($(target).find('td:eq(0)').text());
    $(target).children('td').each((i, e) => {
      $('#showEdit').children('input')[i].value = e.textContent;
    })
    $('#modalExample,#showEdit').css("display", "block");
  } else {
    alert('Please select a Row !!!')
  }
})
```

```css
/**
 * modal css
 **/
.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden */
  position: fixed;
  /*mantener posicion: fixed, enable scroll using absolute*/
  z-index: 1;
  /* index top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* inicio del content modal */
  left: -100;
  top: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {
    top: -300px;
    opacity: 0
  }

  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1
  }
}

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #4a7ac9;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #4a7ac9;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btnGetRowInfo" value="Show Info">
<input type="button" id="btnGetRowEdit" value="Edit data">

<table border="1" id="tableFood">
  <thead>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>available</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>apple</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>banana</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>fish</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>egg</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>64</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!---modal-->
<div id="modalExample" class="modal">
  <!--Content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Record Number #<span id="idNumber"></span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="formModal" data-opcion="default">
      <div align="center" id="showInfo" style="display:none">

      </div>
      <div align="center" id="showEdit" style="display:none">
        <label for="txtId">Id: </label><input type="text" name="txtId" id="txtId" readonly>
        <br>
        <label for="txtName">Name:</label><input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName">
        <br>
        <label for="txtPrice">Price:</label><input type="number" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice">
        <br>
        <label for="txtAvQty">Available qty:</label><input type="number" name="txtAvQty" id="txtAvQty">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <br><br><br>
      <button id="btnOk" name="btnOk" type="button" style="float:left;margin-left:35%;">Ok</button>
      <button id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" type="button" style="float:right;margin-right:35%;">Cancel</button>
      <br><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps, and sorry for the bad English also here is a  for the long post

Comment: How lucky I am to found you! unless it didn't solve the problem directly but helped me so far, I just don't know how to thank you. Aww almost forgot the  so delicious :D

Comment: @Hazem Youre right i forgot to get the id, if you need it i can edit the answer =)

Comment: Well it will be useful for those who will see it later, but I solve it anyway